# plot part of the cuminc output (R)

Tags: r

It's my first time posting here. I'm trying to plot part of the cuminc output, not all. If I plot it all, I can simiply do:

```
>plot(PTAR.CIage4)
```

This gave me too many lines. I just want the 'S' group (5 lines), not all groups. `PTAR.CIage4` is created by:

```
>PTAR.CIage4<-cuminc(ftime=PTARdata$Time,fstatus=PTARdata$event,group=PTARdata$AgeG3,
    cencode="N",subset=(PTARdata$AgeG2!=0 & PTARdata$Time<34))
```

Within PTAR.CIage4, the data looks like this:

```
> str(PTAR.CIage4)
>List of 16
> $ 1 D  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:636] 0 0.19 0.19 0.52 0.52 0.85 0.85 1.21 1.21 1.28 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:636] 0.00 0.00 4.13e-05 4.13e-05 8.25e-05 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:636] 0.00 0.00 1.70e-09 1.70e-09 3.41e-09 ...
> $ 2 D  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:198] 0 0.49 0.49 0.91 0.91 1.14 1.14 1.77 1.77 3.25 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:198] 0 0 0.000233 0.000233 0.000466 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:198] 0.00 0.00 5.44e-08 5.44e-08 1.09e-07 ...
> $ 3 D  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:164] 0 0.55 0.55 2.16 2.16 2.36 2.36 2.62 2.62 2.72 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:164] 0 0 0.000631 0.000631 0.000946 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:164] 0.00 0.00 1.99e-07 1.99e-07 2.98e-07 ...
> $ 4 D  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:208] 0 0.32 0.32 1.37 1.37 2.03 2.03 2.85 2.85 3.67 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:208] 0 0 0.000371 0.000371 0.000742 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:208] 0.00 0.00 1.38e-07 1.38e-07 2.75e-07 ...
> $ 5 D  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:238] 0 1.14 1.14 1.34 1.34 1.9 1.9 2.06 2.06 2.26 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:238] 0 0 0.00186 0.00186 0.00371 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:238] 0.00 0.00 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 6.87e-06 ...
> $ 1 I  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:464] 0 0.98 0.98 2 2 3.35 3.35 3.64 3.64 3.74 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:464] 0.00 0.00 4.13e-05 4.13e-05 8.25e-05 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:464] 0.00 0.00 1.70e-09 1.70e-09 3.41e-09 ...
> $ 2 I  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:56] 0 3.87 3.87 4.53 4.53 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:56] 0 0 0.000233 0.000233 0.000466 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:56] 0.00 0.00 5.44e-08 5.44e-08 1.09e-07 ...
> $ 3 I  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:48] 0 2.26 2.26 5.12 5.12 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:48] 0 0 0.000315 0.000315 0.000631 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:48] 0.00 0.00 9.95e-08 9.95e-08 1.99e-07 ...
> $ 4 I  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:44] 0 2.66 2.66 4.69 4.69 9.75 9.75 9.92 9.92 9.98 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:44] 0 0 0.000371 0.000371 0.000742 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:44] 0.00 0.00 1.38e-07 1.38e-07 2.75e-07 ...
> $ 5 I  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:40] 0 1.14 1.14 7.03 7.03 7.19 7.19 7.78 7.78 10.8 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:40] 0 0 0.00186 0.00186 0.00371 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:40] 0.00 0.00 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 6.87e-06 ...
> $ 1 S  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:1358] 0 3.25 3.25 5.74 5.74 5.78 5.78 6.04 6.04 6.34 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:1358] 0.00 0.00 4.13e-05 4.13e-05 8.25e-05 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:1358] 0.00 0.00 1.70e-09 1.70e-09 3.41e-09 ...
> $ 2 S  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:1082] 0 9.95 9.95 10.57 10.57 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:1082] 0 0 0.000233 0.000233 0.000466 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:1082] 0.00 0.00 5.44e-08 5.44e-08 1.09e-07 ...
> $ 3 S  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:948] 0 6.01 6.01 8.96 8.96 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:948] 0 0 0.000315 0.000315 0.000631 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:948] 0.00 0.00 9.95e-08 9.95e-08 1.99e-07 ...
> $ 4 S  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:908] 0 7.78 7.78 9.72 9.72 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:908] 0 0 0.000371 0.000371 0.000742 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:908] 0.00 0.00 1.38e-07 1.38e-07 2.75e-07 ...
> $ 5 S  :List of 3
>  ..$ time: num [1:472] 0 5.88 5.88 9.29 9.29 ...
>  ..$ est : num [1:472] 0 0 0.00186 0.00186 0.00371 ...
>  ..$ var : num [1:472] 0.00 0.00 3.44e-06 3.44e-06 6.87e-06 ...
> $ Tests: num [1:3, 1:3] 1.12e+03 4.90e+01 7.48e+02 0.00 5.84e-10 ...
>  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "D" "I" "S"
>  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "stat" "pv" "df"
> - attr(*, "class")= chr "cuminc"
```

I don't know how to call the $ 1 S to $ 5 S into a plot. Can any one help me?

Comment: There is a `cuminc` in the `cmprsk` and the `mstate` packages.  Please let us know which one you are using.

Comment: @Shan Cheung, Since you are new on S.O., you might want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). As a courtesy to people that spend their time helping you, and to avoid piles of unanswered questions, you may consider upvoting and/or marking a suitable answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this function will be helpful:

```
cs.cuminc <- function(x,cause="1"){
  if (!is.null(x$Tests)) 
    x <- x[names(x) != "Tests"]
  which.out <- which(unlist(strsplit(names(x), " "))[seq(2,length(names(x))*2,2)]!=cause)
  x[which.out] <- NULL
  class(x) <- "cuminc"
  return(x)
}
```

It can be used to plot the curves for only 1 type of failure, as it removes the removes the results for the other causes of failure from the `cuminc`-object you put in it.

Here's an example adjusted from the cuminc-helpfile:

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(2)
ss <- rexp(100)
gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('a','b','c'))
cc <- sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE)
strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)

# Make cuminc object and plot all curves
xx <- cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt)
plot(xx,lty=1,color=1:6)

# Now use function to only plot the lines for cause="2"
x.2 <- cs.cuminc(xx, cause="2")
plot(x.2,lty=1,color=4:6)
```

The function defaults to cause="1" (has to be entered as string). In case of the OP's example it would look something like:

```
PTAR.CIage4.S <- cs.cuminc(PTAR.CIage4, cause="S")
plot(PTAR.CIage4.S)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to subset your list `PTAR.CIage4` by the names of its elements. A small example:

```
# create a list    
PTAR.CIage4 <- list("1 A" = 1, "2 A" = 2, "1 S" = 3, "2 S" = 4)
names(PTAR.CIage4)

# create a vector of names of the list elements that you wish to select
myelements <- paste(1:2, "S", sep = " ")

# select elements from the list
PTAR.CIage4_sub <- PTAR.CIage4[myelements]
```

The new list can then be used for your plot.

Or why not run `cuminc` on the relevant subset of your data from the start?

**Edit following the comment from @Shan Cheung:**

Run `cuminc` on a subset of the data, using data from `?cuminc`:

```
# generate data
set.seed(2)
ft <- rexp(100)
fs <- sample(x = 0:2, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
grp <- factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
strt <- sample(x = 1:2, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

# run cuminc on all groups
library(cmprsk)
xx <- cuminc(ftime = ft, fstatus = fs, group = grp, strata = strt)
str(xx)
plot(xx, lty = 1, col = 1:6)

# run cuminc on a subset of groups
xx2 <- cuminc(ftime = ft, fstatus = fs, group = grp, strata = strt, subset = grp == "a")
str(xx2)
plot(xx2, lty = 1, col = 1:2)
```

Thus, in your `cuminc` call, you should try `subset = whateveryoucalledthegroupvariable == "S"`. Please provide example data next time, real or simulated, and which package(s) you have used.

```
# my first suggestion, list subsetting, gives the same result
# run cuminc on all groups and subset the resulting list by names of its elements
xx3 <- xx[paste("a", 1:2, sep = " ")]
all.equal(xx2, xx3)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'run cuminc on the relevant subset of my data'. If I assume one of the events/causes is censored, I got different output.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if you want to plot the `$est` vs. the `$time` data in each list element whose name begins with (in pseudo-regex) "[0-9]S" , then one way is

```
#create an empty plot frame
plot(c(min_time,max_time),c(min_est,max_est),t='n')

for(j in 1:(length(PTAR.CIage4)-1) ) {
    if(grepl("S", names(PTARcCIage4)[j]) ) {
         lines(PTARcCIage4[[j]]$time, PTARcCIage4[[j]]$est,...) #or `points` if desired
         }
    }
```